# How to calculate that series

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability

I was looking at the solution of a problem, then this:[image]

I don't know how to caluculate that series in the denominator, and here I assume the result is done by write out that series.

Here X is a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda$, when X = n, we have that each one of the n outcomes has a probability of success $p$, independently of others. Let S denoted as the total number of successes.

Comment: @imranfat sorry I correct that

Comment: And so I took my comment off :)

Answer (score 1):

This expression can be rewritten as 
$$
\Bigg(\frac{p}{1-p} \Bigg)^k e^{-\lambda} \cdot \sum_{m=k}^{\infty} \frac{(\lambda(1-p))^m}{(m-k)!}
$$
Can you handle from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{m=k}^{\infty}p^k(1-p)^{m-k}{m\choose k} \frac{\lambda^m}{m!}e^{-\lambda}$$
$$=e^{-\lambda}\frac{ \lambda^k p^k}{ k!}\sum_{m=k}^{\infty} \lambda^{m-k}(1-p)^{m -k}\frac{1}{ (m-k )!}     $$
$$=e^{-\lambda}\frac{ \lambda^k p^k}{ k!}\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \lambda^{t}(1-p)^{t}\frac{1}{ t!}  = \frac{ \lambda^k p^k}{ k!}e^{-\lambda}e^{\lambda (1-p) } = \frac{ \lambda^k p^k}{ k!} e^{-\lambda  p }. $$